# Maximazing JInternalFrame in JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

So I created a JDesktopPane and JInternalFrame in it (and I'm using windows L&F) but when I maximize the JInternalFrame it's not working as in Windows.I mean the frame should disappear and the 3 buttons [image] should be inside of JMenuBar.

[image]

[image]

Is there any solution to make my JInternalFrame be maximized in JMenuBar ?

Answer (score 2):

I "guess" you're setting the frame's bounds (size/location) to match the size of the `JDesktopPane`.  You should be using [`JInternalFrame#setMaximum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setMaximum(boolean))

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JDesktopPane dp = new JDesktopPane() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(400, 400);
                    }
                };
                JInternalFrame iFrame = new JInternalFrame("Test", true, true, true, true);
                iFrame.add(new TestPane());
                iFrame.setVisible(true);
                iFrame.pack();
                dp.add(iFrame);

                JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu menu = new JMenu("Window");
                JMenuItem mi = new JMenuItem("Maximise");
                mi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JInternalFrame iFrame = dp.getSelectedFrame();
                        if (iFrame != null) {
                            try {
                                iFrame.setMaximum(true);
                            } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                menu.add(mi);

                mi = new JMenuItem("Restore");
                mi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JInternalFrame iFrame = dp.getSelectedFrame();
                        if (iFrame != null) {
                            try {
                                iFrame.setMaximum(false);
                            } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                menu.add(mi);

                mb.add(menu);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(dp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                dp.setSelectedFrame(iFrame);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

> In C# it's a default fonctionality that when u maximize an internal frame it's maximized in menu bar and the blue frame around it disappear, but it's not the same thing in java

This can't be done in Swing...or at least, it can't be done unless you want to completely re-write the look and feel

Comment: still the same problem the JInternalFrame is not maximized in JMenuBar.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: actually I'm not having a problem in code or JInternalFrame maximization I posted  2 pictures that shows what exactly I want. The first pic is a random application (created by C# i guess) as u can see the JInternalFrame is maximized in menu bar.The second pic is my application with java as u can see too the JInternalFrame is maximized but not in JMenuBar like in the first pic.I was asking if this is a bug in java L&F or there is a solution for it.

Comment: In C# it's a default fonctionality that when u maximize an internal frame it's maximized in menu bar and the blue frame around it disappear, but it's not the same thing in java.